# How to find the port a device is connected to, based on IP, on a Cisco Catalyst switch

Tags: cisco, cisco-catalyst, cisco-ios-12, cisco-3750, troubleshooting

On a Cisco Catalyst switch, I need to find what port an end device is connected to.

I have the IP address/host name.

How do I quickly find the port?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The answer depends on whether the switch is a [Layer 2 or a Layer 3](http://www.cisco.com/web/about/ac123/ac147/archived_issues/ipj_1-2/switch_evolution.html) switch.  That is to say, is the switch only switching and relaying traffic on to a different device for routing, or, is it doing the routing decisions itself via SVIs (switched virtual interfaces).

On a layer 3 switch, the port can be found by using a few simple commands on the device.  However on a layer 2 switch, you have to log into both the switch and whatever device is doing the routing to locate the port.

In either case, the commands are the same, just run on two different boxes for the layer 2 switch.

---

### On a Layer 3 switch:

- Log into the switch and issue the following command (where *ipaddress* is the ip address of the host you are trying to locate:

  ```
  show ip arp *ipaddress*
  ```
- The output should look similar to below, and give you the mac-address of the device (I've highlighted the mac-address below in bold).

  ```
  LYKINS-1861#show ip arp 172.20.1.100
  Protocol  Address          Age (min)  Hardware Addr   Type   Interface
  Internet  172.20.1.100            0   **28cf.da1d.1b05**  ARPA   Vlan10
  ```
- Now issue one of the following commands (where *mac-address* is the hardware address from previous step).  Depending on the Cisco platform, sometimes the command is listed in either form.

  ```
  show mac address-table address *mac-address*
  show mac-address-table address *mac-address*
  ```
- The output should look similar to  below, the port you are looking for should be listed as the Destination Port:

  ```
  LYKINS-1861#show mac-address-table address 28cf.da1d.1b05
  Destination Address  Address Type  VLAN  Destination Port
  -------------------  ------------  ----  --------------------
  28cf.da1d.1b05          Dynamic      10     **FastEthernet0/1/1**
  ```

---

### On a Layer 2 switch:

- Find out what device is doing the routing for this switch (you may have to look at the network documentation). Sometimes it is a "[Router on a Stick](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk389/tk815/technologies_configuration_example09186a00800949fd.shtml)", where the Layer 2 VLANs are being trunked up to the router for the Layer 3 decisions.
- Log into the routing device, and issue the following command (where *ipaddress* is the ip address of the host you are trying to locate:

  ```
  show ip arp *ipaddress*
  ```
- The output should look similar to below, and give you the mac-address of the device (listed below in bold).

  ```
  LYKINS-1861#show ip arp 172.20.1.100
  Protocol  Address          Age (min)  Hardware Addr   Type   Interface
  Internet  172.20.1.100            0   **28cf.da1d.1b05**  ARPA   Vlan10
  ```
- Now log into the Layer 2 switch
- On that device issue one of the following commands (where *mac-address* is the hardware address from previous step).  Depending on the Cisco platform, sometimes the command is listed in either form.

  ```
  show mac address-table address *mac-address*
  show mac-address-table address *mac-address*
  ```
- The output should look similar to  below, the port you are looking for should be listed as the Destination Port:

  ```
  LYKINS-1861#show mac-address-table address 28cf.da1d.1b05
  Destination Address  Address Type  VLAN  Destination Port
  -------------------  ------------  ----  --------------------
  28cf.da1d.1b05          Dynamic      10     **FastEthernet0/1/1**
  ```

Comment: Is this lookup possible using SNMP?? I mean a direct lookup and [not like this](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/simple-network-management-protocol-snmp/44800-mactoport44800.html)

Answer (score 13):

Firstly, you need to get the MAC address, so get into a machine on the same VLAN and look at its neighbour table - Windows is `netsh int ipv4 show neigh`, Linux: `ip nei` Cisco: `show ip arp x.x.x.x`. Once you have that...

If this is a discovery job on a layer 2 switch, do `show mac address-table | i 0011.2233.4455` - replacing the mac address bytes as appropriate.

If on the other hand it's a router, use `show ip arp | i 0011.2233.4455` - again replacing the MAC as appropriate. Obviously when you were getting the MAC, if it turned out to be directly connected to that router, you're already done.

Long-term however, I heartily recommend that you setup LLDP (failing that, CDP) to your hosts so that you can identify them from either side. [**lldpd**](http://vincentbernat.github.io/lldpd/) is an absolutely excellent LLDP daemon for Linux that also supports CDP, EDP, SONMP and FDP. If you're currently able to reach the host and it does happen to run linux/BSD, I'd recommend skipping the above and just turn on LLDP.

Comment: +1 for LLDP, it's a nice solution that helps from both sides.

Answer (score 7):

Regardless of whether your switch is performing frame forwarding (layer 2) or packet routing (layer 3), the following should work if the switch has a management IP address in the same subnet as the host you want to find:

1. At the switch, ping the IP address you want to find. If the address is on the same subnet as the switch's management address, an ARP request will be sent looking for the MAC address of the host.
2. Now you can look at the ARP cache and find the MAC address of the host you are looking for (`show ip arp`) and its corresponding interface.
3. You can also look for its MAC address table entry by issuing: `show mac-address table address [the address]`

Answer (score 1):

Quickly?

1. Telnet or SSH into the Cisco switch.
2. Type `terminal monitor`; press enter.
3. Unplug the cable or shut NIC via the
   OS from the endpoint in question

`00:00:47: %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface GigabitEthernet2/0/1, changed state to down`

Note, if you are connecting to the switch from the endpoint you are unplugging you will not get the syslog message because you will have cut connectivity.

Answer (score 1):

Just telnet yourself into the switch, then unplug the device, then replug it.
The switch will write a message which port was down and then up.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Enable ip device tracking on the switch. USe the following commands

ip device tracking
ip device tracking probe delay 30

The second commands prevents the duplicate ip error from popping up on pc's. There is a Cisco bug for it but can't remember the id.

Will want older 12.4 code or 15 code to enable the above.

Answer (score 0):

The CAM table on the switch matches the MAC address to the device port. Use 'show mac address-table' on the switch. You can also configure port descriptions to help find devices later too.

Answer (score 0):

you want to find:
1.At the switch, ping the IP address you want to find. If the address is on the same subnet as the switch's management address, an ARP request will be sent looking for the MAC address of the host.
2.Now you can look at the ARP cache and find the MAC address of the host you are looking for (show ip arp) and its corresponding interface.
3.You can also look for its MAC address table entry by issuing: show mac-address table address [the address]

Answer (score 0):

I have created a few python scripts to help with this and to document the devices connected to the edge switches.

https://github.com/rikosintie

The specific repositories are:
pingSVI - takes the output of "sh run | i ^interface|^_ip address" parses the subnets and pings all hosts. Populates switch's arp table for devices that have timed out.

ARP-Sort - creates a json database of IP-Mac addresses from the core switch

MAC2Manuf - takes the output of "show mac add int" and uses the json database to create a list of IP-MAC-Port-Manufacture off the edge switch.

Answer (score 0):

If you issue the command show mac address-table address x, you could also see this MAC being learned on a trunk port. If that is the case (and assuming you're connected to another Cisco device), use "show cdp nei" and log into that device and perform the same steps as above. Keep doing this until you see the MAC address being learned on a non-trunk port.